# Keras treat Image as array of arrays not a single picture

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

So I have an NN inside of a class

```
      self.model = Sequential()
      self.model.add(Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(240,256,3)))
      self.model.add(Dense(264,activation='relu'))
      self.model.add(Dense(7,activation='relu'))
      self.model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and I have an array that is in shape (240, 256, 3)

```
print(picture.shape) #(240, 256, 3)
picture = np.reshape(picture,(1,240,256,3))
```

and then try to

```
self.model.predict(picture,verbose=1)
```

but instead of output like this `[ 0. 25.21973 0. 0. 0. 1.8569145 0.]` I got something like

```
[[[[ 0.         25.21973     0.         ...  0.          1.8569145
     0.        ]
   [ 0.         25.21973     0.         ...  0.          1.8569145
     0.        ]
   [ 0.         25.21973     0.         ...  0.          1.8569145
     0.        ]
   ...
  [[ 0.         14.3257885   0.         ...  1.7455587   0.
     0.        ]
   [ 0.         25.417042    0.         ...  0.          7.501096
     0.        ]
   [ 0.         24.028965    0.         ... 14.10364     0.
     0.        ]
   ...
   [ 0.         17.480661    0.         ...  3.4586341   0.
     0.        ]]

  [[ 0.         21.477276    0.         ...  0.          0.
     0.        ]
   [ 0.         15.683931    0.         ...  0.          0.
     0.        ]
   [ 0.         10.419488    0.         ...  0.          0.29006004
     0.        ]
   ...

   [ 0.          7.038389    0.         ...  0.          0.
     0.        ]]

  [[ 0.         18.099554    0.         ...  0.          0.
     0.        ]
   [ 0.          8.225699    0.         ...  0.751534    0.
     0.        ]
   [ 0.         13.256775    0.         ...  0.          2.1235647
     0.        ]]]]
```

can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: what happens if you use `picture` array without reshaping ?

Comment: currently, what is the shape of `self.model.predict(picture,verbose=1)` ?

Comment: so witchout reshaping at all ```ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (240, 256, 3)``` but I know it's becouse keras add one dim to the input shape so in fact is (1,240,256,3) so I try to just put this picture in the array witchout reshpaing and put it to a nn but the result was the same

Comment: the shape of ```self.model.predict(picture,verbose=1)``` is (1, 238, 254, 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Keras' `Dense` layers operate on the last dimension of the input, so when you input an image, you get another image as output. The problem is with your model. If you use `model.summary()` you will see that the output shape of your model is actually the one you are seeing through `predict`.

The solution is simple, add a `Flatten` layer after the last `Conv2D`:

```
self.model = Sequential()
self.model.add(Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(240,256,3)))
self.model.add(Flatten())
self.model.add(Dense(264,activation='relu'))
self.model.add(Dense(7,activation='relu'))
```

Then your model will behave as expected.

Comment: That's a good answer I forgot about the ```Flatten()``` thank you